# Where are gems installed from git source?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've installed a gem from git source:

```
gem 'padrino', git: 'git@github.com:padrino/padrino-framework.git'
```

How can I find where it's located on my machine?

Comment: `gem which whenever` may be..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
bundle show padrino
```

and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about being installed locally try  `yourcomp/home/username/~/.rvm/gems/"your_default_ruby_version"/gems` .

Comment: Gems from git are installed differently from ones installed from rubygems.org. And I was using rbenv:)